# Visual Studio extension window not showing up when debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I've developed a Visual Studio extension with two windows that can be displayed via *View->Other Windows->...* It used to work fine but for some reason those windows don't show anymore in the experimental instance of Visual Studio when debugging.

I have set the debugging options to *"Start external program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"* with *"Command line arguments: /rootsuffix Exp"*

As said it used to work and the icons of the windows still show under *View->Other Windows* - they just don't open any window.

I already tried selecting the window with Ctrl+Tab (not listed there) and Ctrl + - + M as recommended [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/10/I-cant-find-my-Find-Dialog-in-Visual-Studio).
Furthermore I tried resetting the experimental VS as described [here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/resetting-visual-studio-experimental-instance-to-its-super-clean-initial-state/) (plus [this tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ca73dffb-0ab4-4b94-a45a-f288112120a3) and resetting the settings of the experimental VS).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error messages/warnings? What is your windows Environment, 32 bit or 64 bit? If you reset VS settings, and then create a new simple VS extension, how about the result?

Comment: @JackZhai No, I don't get any error. Windows 10 64bit and VS 2015. Won't create a new extension for testing right now but I tried resetting the settings of the experimental VS (updated my question) - is there any use of also resetting the standard VS settings?

Comment: Can you share me the steps about how I can repro this issue in my side using the VS IDE? Actually I mean that you could reset your VS settings: TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings.

Comment: @JackZhai I reset my VS settings but that didn't help. I can't tell how this problem came to be, sorry. But I will comment here if I find out.

Comment: if you debug the same app in other VS machine, how about the result? Can you run it using "start without debugging" as the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the issue was that the experimental instance showed an old version of the extension.

Resetting it, increasing the version nr and then doing a clean & rebuild made it use the actual, latest one.

The windows could be shown again by fixing some code in the methods to open the windows...those should contain:
`ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(TestWindow), 0, true);
var windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());`

Comment: Increasing the version fixed it for me.